# Is there any sense to use autoencoder for network with batch normalization?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

As known, main problem in DNN is long time of learning.

But there are some ways to accelerate learning:

1. **Batch Normalization** `=(x-AVG)/Variance`: https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167

> Batch Normalization achieves the same accuracy with **14 times fewer
>   training steps**

2. **ReLU** [`=max(x, 0)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) - rectified linear unit (ReLU,LReLU,PReLU,RReLU): https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.00853

> The advantage of using non-saturated activation function lies in two
>   aspects: The first is to solve the so called “exploding/vanishing
>   gradient”. The second is to **accelerate the convergence speed**.

Or any one: (maxout, ReLU-family, tanh)

3. **Fast weight initialization** (with avoiding vanishing or exploding gradients): https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06856

> Our **initialization** matches the current state-of-the-art unsupervised
>   or self-supervised pre-training methods on standard computer vision
>   tasks, such as image classification and object detection, while being
>   roughly **three orders of magnitude faster**.

Or LSUV-initialization (Layer-sequential unit-variance): https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06422

But if we use all steps: (1) Batch Normalization, (2) ReLU, (3) Fast weight initialization or LSUV - then is there any sense to use [autoencoder/autoassociator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) in any steps of training deep neural network?

Comment: What du you use the autoencoder for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### tl;dr

Autoencoders can be seen as an alternative method to initialize the weights in a smart way. As such, you use autoencoders *instead* of the "fast" weight initialization algorithm you describe.

### More detailed explanation

Autoencoders and RBMs are/were frequently used to pre-train a deep neural network. Early deep neural networks were almost impossible to train, due to the very high-dimensional parameter space. A simple stochastic gradient descent algorithm only converged very slowly and would usually get stuck in a bad local optimum. A solution to this problem was to use RBMs (G. Hinton *et al.*) or Autoencoders (Y. Bengio *et al.*) to pre-train the network in an unsupervised fashion.

This comes with two large advantages:

1. You do not need lots of labeled training data. Often, there is a lot of unlabeled data available (think: images on the internet), but labeling them is a very expensive task.
2. You can *greedily* train them layer-by-layer. That means, you train a first (1-layer) autoencoder. Once you achieve a good reconstruction, you stack another autoencoder on top of that. You train the second autoencoder without touching the first autoencoder. This helps to keep the number of parameters low, and thus makes training simpler and faster.

After training the RBM or autoencoder, you would place an output layer on top of the pre-trained network, and train the *whole* network in a supervised fashion with backpropagation. This step is also called fine-tuning. As all layers except the output layer are already pre-trained, the weights don't have to be changed much, and you will find a solution very quickly.

### Finally, the answer to your question

Does it make sense to use autoencoders? If you have lots and lots of labeled training data, why even bother? Just initialize the weights as smart as you can, and let the GPUs roar for a couple of weeks.

However, if labeled training data is scarce, gather lots of unlabeled data and train autoencoders. With that, you make sure that you achieve a fast convergence and a good solution with the few labeled examples you have.

Comment: Thank you! Pre-trained network by using RBM or autoencoder on lots of unlabeled data allows more faster fine-tuning than any weight initialization. I.e. if I want to train network only once then fast way is "fast weight initialization", but if I want to train network many times then faster way is only once do pre-trained model by using RBM/autoencoder and for each training to use this pre-trained model to fine-tuning.

Comment: Well, that is true too. What I mostly wanted to say is, that even if want to train the network only once, if you just don't have a lot of labeled data available (maybe because it is difficult or expensive to measure), you can use autoencoders to improve the convergence

Comment: if I understood ur answer/point correctly, using BatchNorm is preferred over Auto-encoder if we have enough labeled data and GPU resources?

Comment: You didn't answer the main question about batch normalization.